# cut part of grep output with sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed, grep

I need to get values from log file, values may be different and need to get it.

example of string:

```
Tests run: 1042, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

i try with:

```
cat log.log | grep '^Test run:' | sed -e 's/^Test run: //'
```

but i get:
    1042, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

i need 4 commands that result was like

first command (tests run)

```
1042
```

second command (Failures)

```
0
```

third command (Errors)

```
0
```

fourth commad (Skipped)

```
0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following four commands to obtain the values for `Tests run`, `Failures`, `Errors`, and `Skipped` respectively:

```
cat log.log | sed 's/Tests run: \([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g'
cat log.log | sed 's/.*Failures: \([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g'
cat log.log | sed 's/.*Errors: \([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g'
cat log.log | sed 's/.*Skipped: \([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
grep '^Tests run:' <<END | grep -o '[0-9]\+'
Tests run: 1042, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
junk
Tests run: 1, Failures: 2, Errors: 3, Skipped: 4
END
```

outputs

```
1042
0
0
0
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will be what you want or not, but assuming the lines you are searching for will be in this format:

```
Tests run: <integer>, Failures: <integer>, Errors: <integer>, Skipped: <integer>
```

The following might work for you:

```
sed -e 's/^Tests run: \([0-9]*\), Failures: \([0-9]*\), Errors: \([0-9]*\), Skipped: \([0-9]\).*$/\1,\2,\3,\4/'
```

Given the following input in a file called test.log

```
Tests run: 1042, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
Tests run: 12, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
Tests run: 104, Failures: 1, Errors: 3, Skipped: 4
```

Running:

```
cat test.log | sed -e 's/^Tests run: \([0-9]*\), Failures: \([0-9]*\), Errors: \([0-9]*\), Skipped: \([0-9]\).*$/\1,\2,\3,\4/'
```

Would yield the following output:

```
1042,0,0,0
12,0,0,0
104,1,3,4
```

You could, of course, tweak the final output by playing with the /\1,\2,\3,\4/ part of the sed expression.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
sed -n "s/.*Tests run: \([0-9]*\),.*/\1/p"
sed -n "s/.*Failures: \([0-9]*\),.*/\1/p"
sed -n "s/.*Errors: \([0-9]*\),.*/\1/p"
sed -n "s/.*Skipped: \([0-9]*\)$/\1/p"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
sed -rn 's/^Tests run:\s*//;s/,[^:]+:\s*/\n/gp' log.log
```

Result:

```
1042
0
0
0
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo "Tests run: 1042, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0" | 
sed '/^Tests/{s/[^0-9,]//g;y/,/\n/;}'
1042
0
0
0
```